# Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine Extensions Taggable

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, tagging, doctrine-extensions

I am trying to integrate [DoctrineExtension-Taggable](https://github.com/hilobok/doctrine-extensions-taggable) into Zend Framework 2.
First I added to composer:

```
"anh/doctrine-extensions-taggable": "1.1.*@dev"
```

Then built instances via service manager (in module.config.php):

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'taggableManager' => function($sm) {
            $entityManager = $sm->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
            return new \Anh\Taggable\TaggableManager($entityManager, '\Anh\Taggable\Entity\Tag', '\Anh\Taggable\Entity\Tagging');
        },
       'taggableSubscriber' => function($sm) {
            $taggableManager = $sm->get('taggableManager');
            return new \Anh\Taggable\TaggableSubscriber($taggableManager);                                      
        },
    ),
 ),
```

Once instances created I registered subscriber in EventManager:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        // standart code for driver initialization
    ),
    'eventmanager' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'subscribers' => array(
                'taggableSubscriber',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

This is all what I did. But at this step I have an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\CircularDependencyFoundException' with
>   message 'Circular dependency for LazyServiceLoader was found for
>   instance Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager' in
>   /var/www/html/fryday/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php
>   on line 946

What I am doing wrong?